# Echo | gives me an error

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

So I have this code:

```
echo unknown command: %2. Usage: firefox /del [history|cookies]
```

it gives me: "cookies]" is not a internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I understand why it gives me this error, but i don't know how to fix it. any ideas?

Comment: We need to see the command that you are running, and not just the output...

Comment: try escaping the pipe with a caret **^|**

Comment: it works, Thanksa lot!

Comment: Another way to do it but much more obtuse. `<nul set /p ".=unknown command: %2. Usage: firefox /del [history|cookies]" &echo.`

Answer (score 0):

Just so this has an official answer:

The symbol `|` in batch is the pipe symbol. Therefore it has to be escaped with the standard escape symbol `^` in batch.